# Using of tumblr api

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I am using the Tumblr API and get the information of Tumblr user after authentication, but I can't understand how do I do that.
How to Get user details using Tumblr API in asp.net.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: show what have you tried so far

Comment: https://tumblr.codeplex.com/